# php says failed to open dir: Too many open files

Tags: php, symfony, php-7.1, orocommerce

I have [cwp](http://centos-webpanel.com/) and [orocommerce](https://oroinc.com/orocommerce/) installed. Running a command `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod` giving me

> failed to open dir: Too many open files error

I modified the php conf `max_input_nesting_level = 1500` `ulimit -n 30000`. It didn't help.

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                                          
  [UnexpectedValueException]                                                                                                  

    RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/home/realized/public_html/oro/vendor/oro/commerce/src/Oro/Bundle/PaymentBundle/  
  Resources/translations): failed to open dir: Too many open files
```

I also tried the solution on : [stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691422/php-failed-to-open-stream-too-many-open-files). None seem to help me.
Thanks

Comment: Show the relevant php code.

Comment: @Adder php app/console cache:clear --env=prod this is the code/command in orocommerce I am using.

Comment: did you reboot the server? ulimit only takes effect after reboot most of the times

Answer (score 0):

What value `ulimit` returns?

On local environment I got:

`$> ulimit
unlimited`

And please reboot your operation system after value of `ulimit` is changed.

Comment: It returns unlimited for me too. And yes I did reboot. But no effect.